# COM deployment dependencies

Tags: windows-installer, atl, setup-deployment, merge-module

I have been running in to an issue where a COM dll that I am distributing with my application fails to register because the atl.dll is not registered on the machine.

The quick fix is to have the run regsvr32 on the dll, but I want something a little cleaner then that.

I don't have much experience with deployment and I was wondering if there is a way that I could determine if the atl.dll is registered on the machine and if not I could register it from code.

I currently have a C# custom action for my msi installer so I could possibly add logic there to perform the task.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to include the correct [Merge Module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369820(VS.85).aspx) with your installer. These will be installed to `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Merge Modules`. If you don't find the required files, you probably haven't installed the "Redistributable Components" feature in either the [Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924.aspx) and/or Visual Studio (I think it's unselected in both by default)

- `ATL90.DLL` can be found in `Microsoft_VC90_ATL_x86.msm`
- `ATL80.DLL` can be found in `Microsoft_VC80_ATL_x86.msm`